# VBA Shell(), WSrcipt.Shell and Shell.Application. What else can I try?

Tags: excel, vba, shell

I'm trying to start a (very) proprietary application at work with VBA. I've used plain old Shell("C:\app\app.exe") and with WScript.Shell and Shell.Application I've tried ShellEX.Run and ShellEX.ShellExecute. All methods work, but when I log in to the application, it freezes. Are these methods doing something in the background that could cause the application to freeze? Are there any other methods I could try?

I am able to call the application easily with a batch file or with a PowerShell script. There is something about VBA that this application doesn't seem to like.

Thanks,
J

Comment: does the app that you start in Shell take any opening arguments?

Comment: It does not take any arguments when opened normally, nor are any arguments mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: Does it require any environment variables to be set?

Comment: Try running the shell command with the optional `windowstyle` argument to see if there are any errors hiding: `Shell("C:\app\app.exe", 1)`

Comment: Also, does the application expect to be in a specific directory when launched? Consider launching a `.cmd` file which in turn sets the directory and then launches the application?

Comment: How do you normally start the application?  If via a Start menu item, try examining that and see if it has any particular configuration which you'd need to mimic with your shell call.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions, I tried them all. Unfortunately to no avail. I found this pretty convoluted way of calling an external program: [link](http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.asp?ID=264). I don't know how or why, but it works!